# Vue v-for output to console.log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console.log

The following example prints the list in HTML. The output in HTML is normal. But the output of the same list in `console.log` is duplicated. Why? I could not find an answer, but I noticed the following:

1. if you do not output the `productsCount` variable in the HTML, then duplication in `console.log` does not occur.
2. if you replace the `mounted` hook with `created`, then duplication in the `console.log` also does not occur.

I would be grateful if anyone could explain this behavior.
Vue v2.4.0

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    products: [1, 2, 3],
    productsCount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    cell(product) {
      console.log(product);
      return product;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.productsCount = this.products.length;
  }
}).$mount('#products');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="products">
  <h6>productsCount: {{productsCount}}</h6>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(product, index) in products">
      <span v-html="cell(product)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mounted()` hook is called after the DOM has been mounted, which means the `cell()` method is already called while mounting the DOM.

In your mounted hook you are updating the data property which causes a rerender inturn calling the `cell()` method again. That's the reason you see your log appearing 2 times

Comment: Thanks. And why if you do not output a variable, then the log is not duplicated?

Comment: @abdulmanov.ilmir even though if you do not output a variable in the html,  If the data object  updates it causes a rerender.

Comment: @ Vamsi Krishna In that case, vue is clever :)